# Combine/unite series of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, lapply

I have a data frame like this, that continues to variable length (an even column number):

```
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   
A     B     C     D     E     F
```

I would like the first half of the data frame to form pairs with the second half of the data frame. (In the case above that would be pairs such as AD, BE and CF.)

Taken from another post, I have made this but I can't manage to make a data frame out of it.

```
lapply(1:(ncol(df)/2), function(x) paste(df[,c(x,x+(ncol(df)/2))], collapse = "")) %>% 
data.frame
```

Could someone explain what actually happens in this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what problem you are facing but there are potentially two problems I see. First is that your character variables are actually factors. In that case you will get back underlying indexes rather than the characters. A second potential issue could be in the `paste` function. Writing it like this gives me the right results. You will have to use `rename_all` from `dplyr` to make the variables names usable.

```
lapply(1:(ncol(df)/2), function(x) paste0(df[[x]], df[[x + ncol(df) / 2]])) %>% data.frame
```

Now what is going on here:

Assuming that you will always have an even number of columns, we are dividing that number by two and then for each of that column index, applying the `paste0` function. `paste0` is a simple wrapper for `paste(..., sep = '')`. We are pasting the column x and column x + half the number of columns. In my updated code, I am using `[[]]` because that will return a character vector.